# Error: No module named tinymce

Tags: django, tinymce

I followed the [installation guide](http://django-tinymce.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-1.5/docs/.build/html/installation.html) for django-tinymce and [Using TinyMCE in Django](http://learnedstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/using-tinymce-in-django/),
installed django-filebrowser, django-grapelli and django-tinymce with pip in virtual environment.
Fragments of
settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  ...
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'tinymce',
)
TINYMCE_JS_URL = MEDIA_URL + 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT + 'js/tiny_mce'
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
  'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
  'theme': "advanced",
}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  ...
  (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
  # or (r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root':  os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, "admin/js/tiny_mce")}, 
)
```

_

```
import tinymce
```

in Python is successful, but when I try to run django (version 1.4) server, I get

```
Error: No module named tinymce
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You were rignt, I used another instance of python (by absolute path, not simply "python manage.py runserver"). Please add this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you installed the packages into the wrong virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the module in the right environment. You will have to run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

I was having the same problem. I ran this collectstatic command and after pushing the statics on the server my issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import yourprojectname.tinymce
```

Comment: "ImportError: No module named tinymce". And what I supposed to do with 2 errors? :)