# How to fix "ImportError: No module named dj_database_url" with Django

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, tinymce

I have a similar problem as "[Error: No module named tinymce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930411/error-no-module-named-tinymce)".

I have an error importing both "ckeditor" and "tinymce" libraries. When I run the server I get

```
ImportError: No module named ckeditor_uploader
```

But there is no problem when I import with `python manage.py shell`.

Here is the detail of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                           
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>                                                                                     
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                      
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line   
    utility.execute()                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute                     
    django.setup()                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup                                        
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)                                                                                   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate                                
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)                                                                                     
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 119, in create                                   
    import_module(entry)                                                                                                     
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module                                                 
    __import__(name)                                                                                                         
ImportError: No module named ckeditor_uploader
```

In the virtualenv of my project I have the following libraries installed:

```
$ pip list
argparse (1.2.1)
dj-database-url (0.3.0)
dj-static (0.0.6)
Django (1.8)
django-ckeditor (5.0.2)
django-toolbelt (0.0.1)
gunicorn (19.3.0)
pip (1.5.4)
psycopg2 (2.6.1)
setuptools (2.2)
static3 (0.5.1)
wsgiref (0.1.2)

$ cat requirements.txt 
Django==1.8
argparse==1.2.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
django-ckeditor==5.0.2
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
static3==0.5.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Posts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = RichTextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
)

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
    },
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pip to solve this problem.

```
pip install dj-database-url
```